# IE9 with Google Chrome Frame window.Open issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, window.open, google-chrome-frame

I am using Google Chrome Frame (GCF) with IE9 and when I open a javascript dialog it opens in a tab instead of a dialog.

My IE setting for 'Tabbed Browser Settings' -> 'When a pop-up is encountered:' -> 'Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open'

I use this javascript to open a window:

```
window.open("http://google.com/", "_blank", 
    "location=0,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no");
```

If I change the IE setting to 'Always open pop-ups in a new window' it works. The problem lies in that I need to change that setting on every IE9 computer in the company and the computer administrators are hesitant to do this.

According to Microsoft documentation if you specify a width/height it will open in a dialog but this is not the case when using GCF.

Is there anything I can do (other than changing the setting) that will force the dialog to open in a new window instead of a tab?

Also IE is crafty it tells you it changes the setting but sometimes it actually doesn't so when testing close out of the browser all the way after changing the setting (I got all excited once after it 'worked' but it was actually the setting not updating in IE).

Comment: IE9 has decent support for most web standards.  Why are you resorting to GCF?  Maybe your time would be better spent simply supporting IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the rel="noreferrer" in a standard link (no window.open).
I went through reams of documentation trying to figure this out.
Fortunately ChromeFrame isn't needed as much since IE11 seems to support most things (although IE11 has a horrible memory leak).

[a href="http://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank"]Rel No Referrer Is the Key[/a]